# Bing maps with world spanning polygons not working in IE7 and IE8

Tags: gis, geospatial, bing-maps

I have an application using Bing Maps that draws polygons on a map. For most polygons, the system works fine, and shows the shape correct. However, with huge polygons (covering almost the entire planet), I get errors in IE7 and IE8. The errors are related to a setSize method within the map script (veapicore.js). The map works correctly in IE9 and FF (still working on Chrome). The page is [http://data.nbr.org/Mapping/chinamissilerange]. The first two checkboxes work fine, the third is where the problem is (803 Brigade Base 55).

I can't figure out what could be causing the problem. Does anyone know what this issue could be?

Thanks,
Erick

Comment: I have solved this question. It turns out that IE7 and IE8 have issues with this particular API when everything isn't finished loading. Moving the map javascript to $(window).load fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question. It turns out that IE7 and IE8 have issues with this particular API when everything isn't finished loading. Moving the map javascript to $(window).load fixed the issue.